# Creating long lists of css data attribute selectors

Tags: css, stylus

I'm having a lot of trouble creating a long list of css3 selectors from a list of names using Stylus. No matter how I try to format this block:

```
@-moz-document domain("example.com") {
  friends = name name1 name2 name3

  for user in friends
      div[data-user={user}] > .chat-line__message--badges
          padding-left: 20px
          background-repeat no-repeat
          background-position-x 0px
          background-size 14px

  for user in friends
      div[data-user={user}]
          background-color rgba(0, 0, 255, .2)!important
}
```

The parser always throws the following error at me:

```
ParseError: stylus:322:2 
318| 
319| for user in friends 
320| div[data-user={user}] 
321| background-color rgba(0, 0, 255, .2)!important 
322| } ---------^ unexpected "}"
```

It says unexpected "}", but that "}" is used to close the @-moz-document portion, and when I delete the "}", it returns another error about reaching EoS.

---

If there's an easier way to create a long list of selectors like the following, I'm willing to learn.

```
div[data-user=user1],
div[data-user=user2],
div[data-user=user3],
...
div[data-user=userN]{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! 1/ Do you need to style _all_ values beginning with user, whatever the number? `[data-user^="user"]` would select them. 2/ Does it work with a MQ where it doesn't with `@-moz-document`? Then you should use a [PostCSS plugin](http://postcss.parts) to inject or replace that unusual proprietary at-rule. PostCSS is compatible with whatever you can find in http://browserhacks.com and that's not the case of a lot of tools created before PostCSS.

Comment: @FelipeAls I need to style values of certain users, but the list can be 20+ long so I'd rather do it with a preprocessor.

I have tried it with different MQ, Stylus seems more concerned with the for-loop indentation from what I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was twofold:

First of all, I forgot quotation marks in the [data-user="{$var}"] portion of the code.

Second of all, the Stylus extension seems to not play well with indentation coding. I added brackets to everything and all was well.